# Pyqt5, opening top level widget from a button click, sometimes duplicated button press event occurs

Tags: python, qt, button, pyqt, widget

Given the sample code below, when clicking on the button "Bar", according to my experience, at least 1 in 10 clicks produces 2 newly opened widgets instead of one. This seems to occur only, if the new widget is opened on top of (completely covers) the widget with the button. Any ideas what is happening here?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.Qt import QHBoxLayout

class foo(QWidget):
    def baz(self):
        w = QWidget()
        w.show()
        self.widgets.append(w)
        print(len(self.widgets))
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widgets = []
        lo = QHBoxLayout()
        b = QPushButton("Bar")
        b.pressed.connect(self.baz)
        lo.addWidget(b)
        self.setLayout(lo)

app = QApplication([])
w = foo()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Meanwhhile, one workaround I found is to use the 'released' signal instead of the 'pressed'...

Comment: Use `clicked` or `released`